Is it possible to SSR from a node express server to a nextJS react client without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?
I would like to SSR the homepage from a node express server to a react nextJS client without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
The server and client are in separate directories.
I have verified the server successfully serves this JSX to the browser b/c I can go to localhost:5000 where the server is running and see the rendered HTML.
// server.js file in node express repo
// Serve SSR React component
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const appHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<SSRApp />);

  res.send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>SSR App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="root">${appHtml}</div>
    </body>
    </html>
  `);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

However, when running the nextJS client on port 3000, I'm only able to render the JSX from the server if I use dangerouslySetInnerHTML:
// page.js file in next client repo
import React from "react";

export default async function HomePage() {
  // Fetch the SSR HTML from your Express server
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000", {
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  const ssrHtml = await res.text();

  return (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ssrHtml }} />
    </div>
  );
}

I'm aware you can sanitize the input to reduce risk of XSS attacks but I'd prefer to avoid dangerouselySetInnerHTML all together.
How can I SSR from a node express server to a nextJS react client and allow the client to hydrate the JSX from the server in a nextJS app without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Check out https://interweave.dev/docs/, this library removes the need for dangerouslySetInnerHTML
